# List of AWS files to retrieve from Deep Archive/Glacier

Tags: bash, amazon-s3, awk

So I have a file with a list of AWS files that I want to retrieve from AWS Deep Archive/Glacier.  Similar to this:

```
bucket-name/path/file1.ext
bucket-name/path/file2.ext
bucket-name/path/file3.ext
bucket-name/path/file4.ext
bucket-name/path/file5.ext
bucket-name/path/path/file1.ext
bucket-name/path/file6.ext
bucket-name/path/file7.ext
```

I want to feed this file into a script that will parse out the bucket and then the file location on AWS so it can be passed to a command such as the one below where $y is the bucket and $x is the location of the file in that bucket:

```
aws s3api restore-object --restore-request Days=7,GlacierJobParameters={Tier=Bulk} --bucket "$y" --key "$x"
```

I have an actual script that will copy these back from AWS using the file list so I'm looking to use it too for the retrieval request as well that needs to be done before the file is available.

I have already figured out that I can use this to get the bucket:
`awk -F'/' '{print $1}'`

and this to get the path to the file
`cut -if2- -d '/' $ndir`

Not being a strong coder I'm looking to get some help.  I figure there might be other commands that can be used to loop as well as probably just a single awk line as well but I'm just not getting it right.

Comment: You can pass the output of awk command to a bash array. saying `myarray=$(awk -F'/' '{print $1}' myfile.txt)` will put every bucket value in `myarray`. and you can assign `y` value with this `y=$(myarray[1])` change the number with `n` for `nth` element you want. or loop it in your script. for better understanding please add some samples for the desired output.

Comment: For every line in the file it would run the command like this for line one from our sample file: ```aws s3api restore-object --restore-request Days=7,GlacierJobParameters={Tier=Bulk} --bucket "bucket-name" --key "/path/file1.ext"```

Comment: Sorry for misleading. I wrote in first comment `myarray=$(awk -F'/' '{print $1}' myfile.txt)` This is only storing one element. To write the output to an array, mind outer paranthesis `myarray=($(awk -F'/' '{print $1}' myfile.txt))`

Answer (score 0):

I changed the names of sample directories for better readability

```
$ cat awsfile.txt 
bucket-name_1/path_1/file1.ext
bucket-name_2/path_2/file2.ext
bucket-name_3/path_3/file3.ext
bucket-name_4/path_4/file4.ext
bucket-name_5/path_5/file5.ext
bucket-name_6/path_6/path_9/file1.ext
bucket-name_7/path_7/file6.ext
bucket-name_8/path_8/file7.ext
```

Below is the **`script`** file. Since I can't help you integrating this to your script, I hope this to be a quite clean code for you to understand:

```
$ cat awsscript.sh
#!bin/bash

declare -a buckarr
declare -a extarr

buckarr=($(awk 'sub(/\//," ") {print $1"\t"}' awsfile.txt))
extarr=($(awk 'sub(/\//," ") {print $2"\t"}' awsfile.txt))

buckarrlength=${#buckarr[@]}

for ((i=0; i<buckarrlength; i++))
do
        y=${buckarr[i]}
        x=${extarr[i]}
        echo "Bucket info:" $y "++++ Path to file:" $x "///replace this command line with any command you wish..."
done
```

Output:

```
  $ bash awsscript.sh
    Bucket info: bucket-name_2 ++++ Path to file: path_2/file2.ext ///replace this command line with any command you wish...    
    Bucket info: bucket-name_2 ++++ Path to file: path_2/file2.ext ///replace this command line with any command you wish...
    Bucket info: bucket-name_3 ++++ Path to file: path_3/file3.ext ///replace this command line with any command you wish...
    Bucket info: bucket-name_4 ++++ Path to file: path_4/file4.ext ///replace this command line with any command you wish...
    Bucket info: bucket-name_5 ++++ Path to file: path_5/file5.ext ///replace this command line with any command you wish...
    Bucket info: bucket-name_6 ++++ Path to file: path_6/path_9/file1.ext ///replace this command line with any command you wish...
    Bucket info: bucket-name_7 ++++ Path to file: path_7/file6.ext ///replace this command line with any command you wish...
    Bucket info: bucket-name_8 ++++ Path to file: path_8/file7.ext ///replace this command line with any command you wish...
```

I don't have any `aws` experience but IMO you only need to replace `echo` line with the code line you wish to run and put variables `$x` and `$y` just as in the `echo` line

Does this answer help you?

---

### Extra

See list of elements of array

```
$ echo "${extarr[@]}"
```

See length of elements of array

```
$ echo "${#buckarr[@]}"
```